# Detect block over players head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command to detect if a block is over a players head. I have  only found commands to detect if the block is under a player. Do anyone have a command to detect blocks over players heads? :)

Comment: It's the exact same command, just with different relative coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
/execute @p ~ ~2 ~ testforblock ~ ~ ~ <block>
```

Replace  with the block you would like to sense.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! This really helped me :D